# Webasyst ShopScript 7 ошибка Call to undefined method getLayout code 500 при разработке плагина

Tags: php, webasyst

Занимаюсь разработкой плагина, в котором должно выполняться действие по ajax.

`/webasyst/shop/?plugin=myplugin&action=generateForSelectedProducts`

Действие лежит в файле `/webasyst/shop/plugins/myplugin/lib/actions/backend/shopMyPluginPluginBackendGenerateForSelectedProducts.action.php`. Его код следующий:

```
<?php

class shopMyPluginPluginBackendGenerateForSelectedProductsAction extends waJsonController
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->response = 'hello world';
    }
}
```

При вызове метода через url выходит ошибка:

```
Call to undefined method getLayout code 500
## wa-system/controller/waController.class.php(245)
#0 wa-system/controller/waDefaultViewController.class.php(44): waController->__call('getLayout', Array)
#1 wa-system/controller/waController.class.php(21): waDefaultViewController->execute()
#2 wa-system/controller/waViewController.class.php(46): waController->run(NULL)
#3 wa-system/controller/waFrontController.class.php(255): waViewController->run(NULL)
#4 wa-system/controller/waFrontController.class.php(190): waFrontController->runController(Object(waDefaultViewController), NULL)
#5 wa-system/controller/waFrontController.class.php(84): waFrontController->execute('myplugin', 'backend', 'generateForSele...')
#6 wa-system/waSystem.class.php(649): waFrontController->dispatch()
#7 wa-system/waSystem.class.php(568): waSystem->dispatchBackend('webasyst/shop/')
#8 index.php(95): waSystem->dispatch()
#9 {main}
GET
array(
  'plugin' => 'myplugin',
  'action' => 'generateForSelectedProducts',
)
Params
array()
```

Главный файл плагина, конфиги и прочие сопроводительные файлы созданы. В плагине есть не ajax-контроллеры, которые отрабатывают нормально.

Вероятно ошибка в правилах наименования. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможную причину и решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку. Шаги исправления:

1. Файл
   `shopMyPluginPluginBackendGenerateForSelectedProducts.action.php`
   нужно переименовать в
   `shopMyPluginPluginBackendGenerateForSelectedProducts.controller.php`.
2. Имя класса нужно изменить с `shopMyPluginPluginBackendGenerateForSelectedProductsAction` на `shopMyPluginPluginBackendGenerateForSelectedProductsController`